# Laravel 5.1 blade, compare a var with many values

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to compare a var with many values, like this:

```
{{(
    ((Request::segment(1) == 'A' || Request::segment(1) == 'B' || Request::segment(1) == 'ETC' || ... ) && $menu->link == 'XXX') ? 'visible' : ''
)}}
```

Is there a way to make the comparission with something like this?

```
{{(
    ((Request::segment(1) == my_values(A,B,C,E,...,ETC) && $menu->link == 'XXX') ? 'visible' : ''
)}}
```

I can't edit the values from Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the PHP `in_array` as explained [here](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) ?

```
{{(
   ((in_array(Request::segment(1), ['A','B','C','E',...,'ETC']) && $menu->link == 'XXX') ? 'visible' : ''
)}}
```

Comment: Thanks, picked as the correct one because was the first one and have a link of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `contains()` function of laravel collection.

```php
{{(
    ((collect(my_values(A,B,C,E,...,ETC))->contains(Request::segment(1)) && $menu->link == 'XXX') ? 'visible' : ''
)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use in_array method in PHP.

`{{(
    ((in_array(Request::segment(1), ['A', 'B', 'C', 'ETC']) && $menu->link == 'XXX') ? 'visible' : ''
)) }}`